# When xcode on VM Ware (MAC OS Mavericks, xcode 6.1 beta 2) load storyboard, the black screen is shown?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, screen, osx-mavericks, vmware

I have problem about VM Ware with Xcode.
I got black screen when I load storyboard of a project.
VM Ware with MAC OS Mavericks, xcode 6.1 beta 2.
Please tell me cause and way for fixing this problem!
Thank you!

Comment: VM's ways are inscrutable

Comment: If my storyboard file has many control, many data, when I click it -> I got black screen?

Comment: its taking long on loading or just get the black screen?

Comment: get the black screen when I click storyboard. Maybe I can't load because the file have many control, many data!

Comment: I found way for fixing by DOUBLE CLICK to storybord file.

Comment: If by mistake you close your proyect with the storyboard as last file opened you will loop the error black screen, to fix the issue, use force shutdown on xcode, open other xcode proyect, double click in the storyboard, close, open your initial proyect, done.